# Integrating by parts. A possible typo in the notes from Hairer

Tags: integration, stochastic-analysis, probability

In page 6 of the notes ["Introduction to Stochastic PDE's"](http://www.hairer.org/notes/SPDEs.pdf) from Martin Hairer, one reads:

> $\ \ $ If, on the other hand, we fix $s=t$, we obtain (still in the case $n=1$) via the change of variables $z=|x|^2/4\ell$, the expression $$C(t,t,0,x)=\dfrac{|x|}{8}\int_{\tfrac{|x|^2}{8t}}^\infty z^{-\tfrac32}e^{-z}dz.$$ Integrating by parts, we get $$C(t,t,0,x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{t}}{4}e^{\tfrac{|x|^2}{8t}}+\dfrac{|x|}{4}\int_{\tfrac{|x|^2}{8t}}^\infty z^{-\tfrac12}e^{-z}dz,$$

Let's write it down to check i:

$$C(t,t,0,x) = \frac{|x|}{8}\int^\infty_{\frac{|x|^2}{8t}} z^{-3/2} e^{-z}\,dz \\
= \frac{|x|}{8}\int^\infty_{\frac{|x|^2}{8t}} (-2 z^{-1/2})' e^{-z}\,dz \\
= \frac{|x|}{8} (-2 z^{-1/2}) e^{-z}\bigg]^\infty_{\frac{|x|^2}{8t}}  - \frac{|x|}{4}\int^\infty_{\frac{|x|^2}{8t}} z^{-1/2} e^{-z}\,dz \\
=\frac{|x|}{8} 2 \bigg(\frac{|x|^2}{8t} \bigg)^{-1/2} e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{8t}}  - \frac{|x|}{4}\int^\infty_{\frac{|x|^2}{8t}} z^{-1/2} e^{-z}\,dz \\
=\frac{\sqrt{2t}}{2}  e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{8t}}  - \frac{|x|}{4}\int^\infty_{\frac{|x|^2}{8t}} z^{-1/2} e^{-z}\,dz \\$$

So instead of $\frac{\sqrt{t}}{4}  e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{8t}} $ shouldn't it be $\frac{\sqrt{2t}}{2}  e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{8t}}$? and the sign instead of $+$ shouldn't it be a minus? since we have 
$$\int u'v = uv] - \int uv'$$
and in our case $u = -2z^{-1/2}$ and $v' = - e^{-z}$

Comment: I think I agree with your correction of $\sqrt{2}/2$ constant but I don't see how the integral changes sign in the fourth line down?

Comment: My mistake here, I edited it, thanks!

Comment: I agree with Kevin's comment. One more typo.